# Make circle around bullet in js carousel

Tags: css, carousel

Please, advise how to make circle around the bullet using CSS, when the bullet (slide) is active?

Right now my css code is:

```
.slide-dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  background-color: #FFE600;
}
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Hi. You can use a pseudo-class for that such as `:before` or `:after`. Use the pseudo-class on `.slide-dot.active`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add padding and transparent border to the dot. Use `background-clip: content-box` to prevent the background from effect the padding and border area. Change the color of the border to `currentColor` when active.

`Note:` I've used `currentColor` to control the background and border via one property.

```css
.slide-dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #bbb;
  background-color: currentColor;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.active {
  color: #FFE600;
  border-color: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-dot"></div>
<div class="slide-dot active"></div>
<div class="slide-dot"></div>
<div class="slide-dot"></div>
<div class="slide-dot"></div>
```

Comment: Looking at the snippet, that's exactly what I need, but I when I paste the code, I have different result. Only yellow round border and no yellow dot inside

Comment: I've made changes to `.slide-dot` as well.

Comment: In my case, I just add - box-sizing: content-box; Now it works perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: I mean, I add box-sizing: content-box to .slide-dot of abovementioned css solution, suggested by Ori Drori

Comment: Since your application uses `box-sizing: border-box`, you can also add to the width and height the padding + border width - `height: 16px; width: 16px`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #cfd1d1;
}
```

```html
<!-- The bullets -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dots"><span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span></span>
  <span class="dots"><span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span></span>
  <span class="dots"><span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span></span>
</div>
```

Hope you can get some idea through this :)